# Category of profinite groups

Tags: category-theory

My question is simple:

Is the category of profinite groups an accessible category?

Thank you

Comment: @PeteL.Clark That only shows that profinite groups are not closed under colimits in topological groups, however. For instance, the category of compact Hausdorff spaces is cocomplete but not closed under colimits in the category of all topological spaces.

Comment: @user48900 I'm inclined to believe the answer is no, but for a different reason: the category of profinite groups is the pro-completion of the category of finite groups, so its _opposite_ is an accessible category. There is a result that says that the opposite of a _locally presentable_ category is locally presentable if and only if it is a preorder, but unfortunately that is not applicable in this case.

Comment: @Zhen: It seems that I'm very confused then: isn't e.g. the integers with the discrete topology a colimit of compact Hausdorff spaces?  **Added**: OK, I saw a relevant MO question.  I think I understand your comment now: there is a compact Hausdorff space which satisfies the right universal property *when restricted to compact Hausdorff spaces* only.

Comment: Yes, in the category of topological spaces. But in the category of compact Hausdorff spaces, the coproduct of countably many copies of $1$ is the ultrafilter space $\beta \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @Zhen: But locally presentable is more restricted than accessible, no?

Comment: Maybe this question should be asked on MathOverflow, by the way...

Comment: @user48900 Yes, as I said. My point is that there is no reason to expect it to be accessible – if it is then it is some kind of accident. (For example, the category of profinite _abelian_ groups is definitely not accessible: because it is equivalent to the opposite of the category of torsion abelian groups, which _is_ locally presentable.)

Comment: @Zhen: Doesn't this imply that the whole category of profinite groups is not accessible as well?

Comment: If you want this question to be on MathOverflow, ask for it to be migrated. Please don't crosspost!

Comment: The other thread has an answer now, so voting to close this one as a duplicate.